# How to search for a string in a category name?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the search result and I GET

```
$s = $_GET['s'];
```

Which gives: "mario"

Now there is a category named `Mario Bianchi` under a main category called `Persone`

When I GET `$s` I need to get all posts within that category, I tried the following but I get nothing

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'name__like' => $s,
    'hide_empty' => true // Optional 
) );
if ( count($terms) > 0 ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $term->name ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Yet I need the actual post attached, not the category itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_terms` does just that, it get the terms for your query. What you'll want is `WP_Query` with a `tax_query`. You've already got the categories you want to return the posts for, so it shouldn't be too difficult

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'category',
    'name__like' => $s,
    'hide_empty' => true // Optional 
) );

$term_ids = array();

if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'terms'    => $term_ids,
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Comment: ok let me try this, p.s.  `syntax error, unexpected '{' ` on `if ( ! empty( $terms ) {`

Comment: it is not looking in category, only finds a match of `$s` in a title, but let's say I search for `mario` and I have a category called `mario bianchi`, I need all posts within that category since we found a match of `$s` (mario) in a category since we have one `mario bianchi`

Comment: if I do `$term_ids = array(); var_dump($terms);` i `get array(0) {}` but we do have a category called `mario bianchi`

Comment: @rob.m It seems to be working for me on a test site: http://xanthous-lion.w5.poopy.life/?s=mario

Comment: in your link i see "NOTHING FOUND
Hello world!
Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords."

Comment: `Hello world` has the "mario bianchi" category

Comment: what if "mario" is a sub category of "persone" tho?It doesn't appear to be including to search in childrens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183674/discussion-between-rob-m-and-cameronjonesweb).

Comment: is there anyhow we could do the same but for tags?

Comment: go it, I had to use 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag'